# react-native expo publish showing a white screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a very strange behaviour with a react native app building with Expo Kit. Things can run local, but just show a white screen when I publish or build apk/ipa. Here is pcakage.json

```
{
  "name": "ezymo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.6.1",
    "jest-cli": "^21.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "^22.0.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.2",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "expo": "^22.0.2",
    "lodash.times": "^4.3.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "^0.49.5",
    "react-native-camera": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.22",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "when": "^3.7.8"
  }
}
```

It's very strange that didn't happen for my other projects. Anyone encounter before and any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution yourself?

Comment: Same as @freeall, wondering if you found a fix for this. I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot, afaict you can't really see logs when running in expo.

Comment: @eric, I fixed mine, but I can't exactly tell you what I did. Upgraded modules, downgraded modules, removed node_modules a dozen times. But because I upgrade react-native, then some babel had changed, so I had to update some code. And after doing that it worked... not sure I learned anything from any of it, though.